# GORM Where query composition on return value

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I noticed some behaviour I don't quite understand. It's possible to chain where queries as long as the preceding where query wasn't returned from a function.

```
def w = Subscription.where { topicId == 1 }
w.where { user.id == 1 }.findAll()

//works as expected


def f() {
    Subscription.where { topicId == 1 }
}
f().where { user.id == 1 }.findAll()

//doesn't filter by user.id


def f() {
    Subscription.where { topicId == 1 }
}
f().build { eq 'user.id', 1L }

//works
```

I don't mind using DetachedCriteria#build(). I'd just like to understand :-D

--- Edit

Grails 2.4.2

Comment: Why don't you try using `findAllBy()` and createCriteria with `alias`?

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks Well, there's no actual problem to solve, I'd just like to understand why Groovy behaves that way. Also, the code above is just a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails contains a global AST transformation...

> that transforms where methods into detached criteria queries.

It essentially looks for uses of `where()` and changes the code so that it uses detached criterias. Most likely, calling `where()` as you are, on the return of a method, particularly a method which returns `Object`, is not being acknowledged up by the AST, so the query basically ends up being unchanged and doing nothing.

It's nothing that Groovy is doing, but rather something Grails-specific. I do not claim a full, nor anything near full, understanding of what's happening, but you can get the gist of it by looking at the [DetachedCriteriaTransformer](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/9fa9aa17d028bdbc9da3895741f9997dab3e2ba5/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/query/transform/DetachedCriteriaTransformer.java) source code.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thank you!